# issues adding the values of an array. Information is concatenated and not summed

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a function that finds the numbers that are divisible by three, and then adds all of those numbers. For example, 21 is divisible by 3, 6,9,12,15,18, and 21.

I then want to add those number, and the result would be 84. I am able to get the information to the array, and then loop through each array element, but when I add them it seems to be concatenating the array as a string and not adding the numbers.

I have tried converting the variables to numbers, but I cannot figure out where I am going wrong.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", solution);
var outPutID = document.getElementById("outPutID");
function solution() {
    var userInput1 = document.getElementById("userInput1ID").valueAsNumber;
    var myArray = [];

    var timesToAdd = parseFloat(userInput1 / 3);
    var remainder = parseFloat(userInput1 % 3);
    var total = (userInput1 - remainder) / 3;

    for (i = 0; i < total; i++) {

        var sum = 3 + (3 * i);
        myArray[i] = parseInt(sum);

    }

    var sumArray;
    for (a = 0; a < myArray.length; a++) {

        sumArray += myArray[a];

    }
    outPutID.innerHTML = sumArray;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="21" id="userInput1ID">
<input type="button" value="Go" id="btn">
<hr>
<div id="outPutID"></div>
```

Comment: `21/6=3.5` so can you please define `21 is divisible` cause it's also divisbile then with 4, 5, especially `7` . . .

Comment: it looks like, you have a value as a string type, you need to convert to number before adding. btw, `myArray[i] = parseInt(sum);` there `parseInt` makes no sense, becaus you have already an integer number. what is `valueAsNumber`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with the code:

- You're using `parseFloat` and `parseInt` on numbers. There's no need or point to doing that, they're *already* numbers.
- You never declare `i` or `a`, so the code is falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*

...but the **main** issue is that `sumArray` is never given an initial value, so it takes the default value of `undefined`. Then you use `+=` on that with a number:

```
sumArray += myArray[a];
```

`undefined + anyNumber` is `NaN`, and `NaN + anyNumber` is `NaN`.

You need to assign `0` to `sumArray` at the outset:

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", solution);
var outPutID = document.getElementById("outPutID");
function solution() {
    var userInput1 = document.getElementById("userInput1ID").valueAsNumber;
    var myArray = [];

    var timesToAdd = userInput1 / 3;
    var remainder = userInput1 % 3;
    var total = (userInput1 - remainder) / 3;

    for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {

        var sum = 3 + (3 * i);
        myArray[i] = sum;

    }

    var sumArray = 0;
    for (var a = 0; a < myArray.length; a++) {

        sumArray += myArray[a];

    }
    outPutID.innerHTML = sumArray;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" value="21" id="userInput1ID">
<input type="button" value="Go" id="btn">
<hr>
<div id="outPutID"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was more that I had not converted a string into an integer. In frustration, I added the parseInt, and parseFloat. Thanks for pointing this out.